# jQuery UI themed radio button has weird icons in background

Tags: jquery-ui, background, radio-button

The last radio shows like this:
[radio background](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T4IfD.png)

When selected the icon background goes away. I tried toggling every single background from dev tools to no avail. Removing the icon images from project folder fixed the background, but renders my checkboxes useless, as they can't be visually checked without the images, so it's no solution. How do I fix this annoying bug?

EDIT:
I will assume the downvotes are because I did not provide code.
Here:

```
<!-- html stuff -->
<label for="21">
  <input id="21" type="radio" name="bbNumber" value="1" />
  Percent(%)
</label>
<label for="22">
  <input id="22" type="radio" name="bbNumber" value="2" />
  Number
</label>
<label for="23">
  <input id="23" type="radio" name="bbNumber" value="0" checked />
  Disable
</label>
<!-- more html stuff -->
```

JS

```
$(function(){
 //unrelated stuff
 $('input[type="checkbox"], input[type="radio"]').checkboxradio();
 //some more stuff
});
```

No custom CSS meddling with radio. The only CSS I have used is for jQ - Autocomplete.

jQuery v 3.3.1
jQ UI v 1.12.1
Black Tie theme from Themeroller > Gallery

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please provide a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve Things to include, the version of jQuery and jQuery UI that you are using. Any custom themes. Any other CSS that might disrupt jQuery UI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of fiddling, I came up with this crude, but working solution. The background in question belonged to an auto-generated *span* element from jQ-UI. I spotted the correct background image, wrapped all the radios in a unique *div* and applied the following CSS rule:

```
#id span.ui-checkboxradio-icon {
  background-image: url('/PATH/TO/BACKGROUND.PNG') !important;
}
```